# Facing difficulty in applying custom font-weight style over react-bootstrap css in react application

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, fonts

I've tried many ways of overriding the default bootstrap css but to no avail in my "Home.jsx" component. This is my Home.jsx (a component to render home screen).

```
import React from "react";

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="center" style={{ fontWeight: 700 }}>
      <h6>Hey! I am</h6>
      <h1>Abhuday Mishra</h1>
      <h3>
        a <span className="desc">Web Developer.</span>
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

This is my App.jsx

```
import MainNav from "./Navbar";
import Home from "./Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MainNav />
      <Home />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And finally this is my styles.css

```
.center {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 14.8%;
}
.center h1 {
  font-size: 75px;
}
.center h6 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.navlink {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.desc {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbrand {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.logo {
  height: 35px;
  width: 120px;
}
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: rgb(234, 255, 208);
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(234, 255, 208, 1) 50%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 51%
  );
}
```

I've tried overriding the bootstrap css, inline styling, using css modules but nothing seems to be working. But when I use the inspect tool in Chrome and turn the font weight on manually, it works fine.
Thanks

Comment: !important  ??? have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I think i is a problem of `css` ordering.
you need to add your css file after the bootstrap one.

I don't know in which order you have imported the bootstrap and added your css file
but the order of css should be like below, then you will override the bootstrap css
bootstrap.css
styles.css